# Lambda: node https request inside promise not returning response every time

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am calling an API gateway URL from a Lambda using HTTPS request inside promise, the code looks like:

```
async function invoke(args) {
  console.log("Calling API")  <----- Logging on cloud watch
  const { options, postData } = args
  let errorObj = {
    status: '500',
    ErrorCode: 'null'
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Inside Promise")  <----- Logging on cloud watch
    const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log("Inside https request>>", res)  <-- NOT LOGGING
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let body = []
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log("Inside On data") <-- NOT LOGGING
        body.push(chunk)
      })

      res.on('end', () => {
        console.log("Inside end") <-- NOT LOGGING
        try {
          if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
            reject(errorObj)
          }
          resolve(body)
        } catch(e) {
            reject(errorObj)
        }
      })
    })

    req.on("error", err => {
      console.log('req error >>', err)
      reject(err)
    })

    console.log('req>>', req)  <----- Logging on cloud watch
    if (postData) {
      req.write(JSON.stringify(postData))
    }
    req.end()
  })
}
```

I am calling "invoke' method from handler. Am I missing anything. Whenever I send a smaller payload I can see all the console logs, but payload size of 2MB skips the request method, but in API gateway I can still see the request going. Why invoke method not waiting for the response to be resolved. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check that you are using the **await** keyword when calling invoke() from the handler

e.g. `e.g. const result = await invoke()`

Comment: Please don't ask questions in answers. It triggers the systems in place to check for NAA. Your answer isn't NAA though. So please edit it to make it look like an answer. :)